Best PowerShell method to get the current Active Directory Site name of the local computer
What are the different ways to get the current Active Directory (AD) site in PowerShell - and which is the fastest, most efficient, and works under the most scenarios?

There are a number of methods available:

Using the nltest.exe command line tool - does not generate network traffic, returns the previous AD site even when offline, but because you are shelling out to a command it is slow, and you need to make sure you test $LASTERRORCODE afterwards in case of errors:

(& "$env:SystemRoot\System32\nltest.exe" /DSGETSITE)[0]

Using .NET - faster, and useful if you need the full site information as well as the name - however please note that any calls using this .NET class generates traffic to your local domain controller:

[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectorySite]::GetComputerSite().Name

Using the registry (Netlogon key) - does not generate network traffic, fast, but be aware that sometimes on domain controllers this value does not exist or may be incorrect:

(Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Netlogon\Parameters').DynamicSiteName

Using the registry (Group Policy key) - does not generate network traffic, fast, works even on domain controllers, but only updates after a successful Group Policy refresh (by default takes up to 90 minutes):

(Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine').'Site-Name'

Using WMI to access the Win32_NTDomain class - don't do this - it is super slow, as well as generating network traffic every time you run it:

(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_NTDomain -Filter 'DomainControllerName != NULL' -Property ClientSiteName).ClientSiteName

(My personal favourite) Using the AdSystemInfo COM object - does not generate network traffic, will throw normal PowerShell errors without additional error handling, works on all devices, and fast.

[__ComObject].InvokeMember('SiteName', 'GetProperty', $null, (New-Object -ComObject ADSystemInfo), $null)
Options 1-3: https://powershellmagazine.com/2013/04/23/pstip-get-the-ad-site-name-of-a-computer/
Option 4: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Get-ADSiteName/1.0/Content/Get-ADSiteName.ps1
Option 5: https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/4cjdk8/get_the_ad_site_name_of_a_computer/
Option 6: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/iadsadsysteminfo-property-methods
